# How to insert timestamp into mysql with php properly?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table num structure:

```
mysql> show columns from num;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| ip    | char(20)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| time  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I insert record with the following codes:

```
<?php   
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $time=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    $db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","passwd");
    $query="insert into  num(ip,time) values('$ip','$time')";
    mysql_select_db('numdb');
    mysql_query($query, $db);
    mysql_close();
    echo "ok";
?>
```

The time is wrong after i inserted two records into table num,
What is matter with my database or php code?

```
mysql> select * from num;
+-----------+---------------------+
| ip        | time                |
+-----------+---------------------+
| 127.0.0.1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 127.0.0.1 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-----------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Did you echo -> `$time=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert the current timestamp, use:

```
$query="INSERT INTO num(time) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

If your server time is different from what you want, you can add hours (or minutes, etc) to the timestamp:

```
$query="INSERT INTO num(time) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 6 HOUR)";
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to use the REQUEST_TIME value instead of the current time. Fortunately, php makes it easy to convert the string format of the request time into an internal time format, then convert that to the

```
2015-03-14 15:19:27
```

standardized string format needed by MySQL to represent a timestamp. This line will give you the workable datestring.

```
  $datestring = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
```

If you don't care about the distinction between the REQUEST_TIME and the current time, simply don't mention the `timestamp` column in your `INSERT` query, and MySQL will use the default (the present time).

Pro tip:  Don't name a column `timestamp` because that's a reserved word. You have to wrap it in backticks in some contexts. Many developers use `ts` for this.